# Yosemite and python matplotlib issue

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, osx-yosemite

Python codes were working well until I upgraded to Yosemite. Any idea please? Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/will/Downloads/legend_demo4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.image import FigureImage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libpng12.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Try re-installing matplotlib.

Comment: I suspect what happened is that they (apple) moved a library under you so mpl is looking for one version, but the OS has another.

Comment: Can you provide details about a) how you installed python b) how you are trying to build the source?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3694

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I fixed that by un- (via: easy_install -m matplotlib) and reinstalling (via: python setup.py build; python setup.py install) the matplotlib from the [sources](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) and afterwards install the [wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=matplotlib&version=1.4.1&:action=display) package (via: pip install packagename.whl).

Comment: You should only have to install from source _or_ from the wheels, not both.